# Mean imputation of selected columns using rowMeans()

Tags: r

[row imputations using selected columns using rowMeans(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPeMr.png)

i  want to impute 4 th column to 8th column without disturbing the remaining columns.
How do i achieve this using rowMeans functionality in R
Thanks in advance.
you can find the image by clicking on picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps we can use `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
df1[4:8] <- lapply(df1[4:8], na.aggregate)
```

If we need it based on rows, use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
df1[4:8] <- t(apply(df1[4:8], 1, na.aggregate))
```