# How can I get the average (mean) of selected columns and impute the NA's

Tags: r, data-analysis

this question can be viewed as extension to the thread below:
([How can I get the average (mean) of selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490485/how-can-i-get-the-average-mean-of-selected-columns)).           How do we impute the missing values ie., NA"s using the mean of the selected columns.

Comment: You posted a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844402/mean-imputation-of-selected-columns-using-rowmeans/38844456#38844456) one hour back and when you got the solution, suddenly deleted the post.

Comment: i didn't understand the solution. i was not trying to create separate data frame.

Comment: In the solution, it was not creating any separate dataset.  It just updates the column NA with the mean values.  Also, posting similar questions (after deleting the previous post) is somewhat abusing the system.

Comment: could you give the solution again please.My fault I will not delete threads here on.

Comment: Here is the solution `library(zoo);
df1[4:8] <- lapply(df1[4:8], na.aggregate)`

Comment: an extension to the above question if i want to place median values to impute NA's How can that be acheived and what are some good resources to learn more about ZOO package

Comment: The linked question is undeleted now. If @akrun's answer provides the requested solution I suggest that you accept that answer and delete this question here.

Comment: i did not find any link on my dashboard stating undeleted

Comment: Okay, I posted the solution

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are doing, but possibly you should use more advanced imputation techniques. You should have a look at the Amelia or mice package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `na.aggregate` from `zoo` to impute the missing values (NA) with the `mean` value of that column.  We loop through the selected columns of dataset (`lapply(df1[4:8], .`), apply the function and then update the columns on the lhs of `<-`

```
library(zoo)
df1[4:8] <- lapply(df1[4:8], na.aggregate)
```

If we need the `median`, use the `FUN` as `median` (by default it is `mean`)

```
df1[4:8] <- lapply(df1[4:8], na.aggregate, FUN = median)
```